# How to personalize the welcome greeting in Dialogflow based on who's calling?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm using Google Dialogflow with the Phone Gateway Integration. Basically, when someone calls in, I would like to greet them in a personalized way using their name (if their number is in our database).

Should I use a webhook? How can the response be adapted for each caller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need webhook here.
A simple database query with the mobile number will get you the name of user.
Then you can have single or multiple response templates.

```
e.g. Hello {user_name}, how may I help you today.
```

If you already have the name of user in your parameter, then you can directly use that in DIalogflow response as well. To use parameter in dialogflow response you need `$` sign. e.g. `$user_name`.

Comment: How do you get the number that called into the Phone Gateway?

Comment: @Prisoner i am assuming OP have their number somehow that is why he has mentioned `personalized way using their name (if their number is in our database)`

Comment: I understand, but they have to get the number from the conversation somehow to match it to what is in the database. Does Dialogflow provide this? (sincere question - I don't know).